# addFeatures doesn't seem to be taken in my code

Tags: openlayers-3, extjs6

I'm working on openlayers 3 and ExtJS 6. I have a vector who is loaded with a GeoJson. I clear it and I want to add some new features once it's cleared.
My new data are provided by a store. So this is what I want to add in my vector :

```
[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"SCALERANK":6,"NATSCALE":30,"LABELRANK":5,"FEATURECLA":"Populated place","NAME":"Marsabit","NAMEPAR":null,"NAMEALT":null,"DIFFASCII":0,"NAMEASCII":"Marsabit","ADM0CAP":0,"CAPALT":0,"CAPIN":null,"WORLDCITY":0,"MEGACITY":0,"SOV0NAME":"Kenya","SOV_A3":"KEN","ADM0NAME":"Kenya","ADM0_A3":"KEN","ADM1NAME":"Eastern","ISO_A2":"KE","NOTE":null,"LATITUDE":2.329999,"LONGITUDE":37.979997,"CHANGED":1,"NAMEDIFF":0,"DIFFNOTE":"Changed scale rank.","POP_MAX":16460,"POP_MIN":15361,"POP_OTHER":16460,"RANK_MAX":6,"RANK_MIN":6,"GEONAMEID":187585,"MEGANAME":null,"LS_NAME":"Marsabit","LS_MATCH":1,"CHECKME":0,"MAX_POP10":16460,"MAX_POP20":16460,"MAX_POP50":0,"MAX_POP300":0,"MAX_POP310":0,"MAX_NATSCA":20,"MIN_AREAKM":12,"MAX_AREAKM":12,"MIN_AREAMI":5,"MAX_AREAMI":5,"MIN_PERKM":17,"MAX_PERKM":17,"MIN_PERMI":10,"MAX_PERMI":10,"MIN_BBXMIN":37.975,"MAX_BBXMIN":37.975,"MIN_BBXMAX":38.033333,"MAX_BBXMAX":38.033333,"MIN_BBYMIN":2.325,"MAX_BBYMIN":2.325,"MIN_BBYMAX":2.341667,"MAX_BBYMAX":2.341667,"MEAN_BBXC":38.004167,"MEAN_BBYC":2.333333,"COMPARE":0,"GN_ASCII":"Marsabit","FEATURE_CL":"P","FEATURE_CO":"PPL","ADMIN1_COD":3,"GN_POP":15361,"ELEVATION":0,"GTOPO30":1344,"TIMEZONE":"Africa/Nairobi","GEONAMESNO":"Geonames ascii name + lat.d + long.d matching.","UN_FID":0,"UN_ADM0":null,"UN_LAT":0,"UN_LONG":0,"POP1950":0,"POP1955":0,"POP1960":0,"POP1965":0,"POP1970":0,"POP1975":0,"POP1980":0,"POP1985":0,"POP1990":0,"POP1995":0,"POP2000":0,"POP2005":0,"POP2010":0,"POP2015":0,"POP2020":0,"POP2025":0,"POP2050":0,"CITYALT":null},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.979996702838946,2.329998595077768]},"NAME":"Marsabit","id":"AIS_LIVE.model.PlacesModel-13153"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"SCALERANK":7,"NATSCALE":20,"LABELRANK":3,"FEATURECLA":"Populated place","NAME":"Marsala","NAMEPAR":null,"NAMEALT":null,"DIFFASCII":0,"NAMEASCII":"Marsala","ADM0CAP":0,"CAPALT":0,"CAPIN":null,"WORLDCITY":0,"MEGACITY":0,"SOV0NAME":"Italy","SOV_A3":"ITA","ADM0NAME":"Italy","ADM0_A3":"ITA","ADM1NAME":"Sicily","ISO_A2":"IT","NOTE":null,"LATITUDE":37.805404,"LONGITUDE":12.438662,"CHANGED":0,"NAMEDIFF":0,"DIFFNOTE":null,"POP_MAX":77784,"POP_MIN":43179,"POP_OTHER":42587,"RANK_MAX":8,"RANK_MIN":7,"GEONAMEID":2524245,"MEGANAME":null,"LS_NAME":"Marsala","LS_MATCH":1,"CHECKME":0,"MAX_POP10":43179,"MAX_POP20":43179,"MAX_POP50":0,"MAX_POP300":0,"MAX_POP310":0,"MAX_NATSCA":20,"MIN_AREAKM":19,"MAX_AREAKM":19,"MIN_AREAMI":7,"MAX_AREAMI":7,"MIN_PERKM":25,"MAX_PERKM":25,"MIN_PERMI":16,"MAX_PERMI":16,"MIN_BBXMIN":12.425,"MAX_BBXMIN":12.425,"MIN_BBXMAX":12.491667,"MAX_BBXMAX":12.491667,"MIN_BBYMIN":37.766667,"MAX_BBYMIN":37.766667,"MIN_BBYMAX":37.816667,"MAX_BBYMAX":37.816667,"MEAN_BBXC":12.458631,"MEAN_BBYC":37.794643,"COMPARE":0,"GN_ASCII":"Marsala","FEATURE_CL":"P","FEATURE_CO":"PPL","ADMIN1_COD":15,"GN_POP":77784,"ELEVATION":0,"GTOPO30":7,"TIMEZONE":"Europe/Rome","GEONAMESNO":"Geonames ascii name + lat.d + long.d matching.","UN_FID":0,"UN_ADM0":null,"UN_LAT":0,"UN_LONG":0,"POP1950":0,"POP1955":0,"POP1960":0,"POP1965":0,"POP1970":0,"POP1975":0,"POP1980":0,"POP1985":0,"POP1990":0,"POP1995":0,"POP2000":0,"POP2005":0,"POP2010":0,"POP2015":0,"POP2020":0,"POP2025":0,"POP2050":0,"CITYALT":null},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.43866166041903,37.805404275558374]},"NAME":"Marsala","id":"AIS_LIVE.model.PlacesModel-10722"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"SCALERANK":4,"NATSCALE":50,"LABELRANK":3,"FEATURECLA":"Admin-1 region capital","NAME":"Marseille","NAMEPAR":null,"NAMEALT":"Marseille-Aix-en-Provence","DIFFASCII":0,"NAMEASCII":"Marseille","ADM0CAP":0,"CAPALT":0,"CAPIN":null,"WORLDCITY":0,"MEGACITY":1,"SOV0NAME":"French Republic","SOV_A3":"FRA","ADM0NAME":"France","ADM0_A3":"FRA","ADM1NAME":"Provence-Alpes-C-te-d'Azur","ISO_A2":"FR","NOTE":null,"LATITUDE":43.289979,"LONGITUDE":5.37501,"CHANGED":4,"NAMEDIFF":0,"DIFFNOTE":"Changed feature class.","POP_MAX":1400000,"POP_MIN":794811,"POP_OTHER":813666,"RANK_MAX":12,"RANK_MIN":11,"GEONAMEID":2995469,"MEGANAME":"Marseille-Aix-en-Provence","LS_NAME":"Marseille","LS_MATCH":1,"CHECKME":0,"MAX_POP10":946129,"MAX_POP20":1034294,"MAX_POP50":1034294,"MAX_POP300":0,"MAX_POP310":0,"MAX_NATSCA":50,"MIN_AREAKM":285,"MAX_AREAKM":361,"MIN_AREAMI":110,"MAX_AREAMI":140,"MIN_PERKM":237,"MAX_PERKM":327,"MIN_PERMI":147,"MAX_PERMI":203,"MIN_BBXMIN":5.158333,"MAX_BBXMIN":5.183333,"MIN_BBXMAX":5.633333,"MAX_BBXMAX":5.633333,"MIN_BBYMIN":43.216667,"MAX_BBYMIN":43.216667,"MIN_BBYMAX":43.466123,"MAX_BBYMAX":43.525,"MEAN_BBXC":5.397504,"MEAN_BBYC":43.351337,"COMPARE":0,"GN_ASCII":"Marseille","FEATURE_CL":"P","FEATURE_CO":"PPLA","ADMIN1_COD":0,"GN_POP":794811,"ELEVATION":0,"GTOPO30":54,"TIMEZONE":"Europe/Paris","GEONAMESNO":"Geonames ascii name + lat.d + long.d matching.","UN_FID":187,"UN_ADM0":"France","UN_LAT":43.28,"UN_LONG":5.38,"POP1950":756,"POP1955":798,"POP1960":929,"POP1965":1069,"POP1970":1182,"POP1975":1253,"POP1980":1295,"POP1985":1307,"POP1990":1305,"POP1995":1331,"POP2000":1357,"POP2005":1386,"POP2010":1400,"POP2015":1418,"POP2020":1445,"POP2025":1469,"POP2050":1490,"CITYALT":"Marseille"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[5.37306427182989,43.29192492260455]},"NAME":"Marseille","id":"AIS_LIVE.model.PlacesModel-13925"}]
```

But if I execute:  `me.getData('myVector').getSource().addFeatures(myData)`

I've got an error.

I also tried

```
 var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
            me.getData('myVector').addFeatures(format.readFeatures( myData, {
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            } ) );
```

It gives me 0 error but I when I want to display all my features there is nothing in my vector.

How can I do?

Comment: Where does `me.getData()` come from?

Comment: it's a extJS 6.0 feature, to be simple 'me' is the scope

Comment: The data you provide suppose to be geojson. But its not proper geojson. You need to get your data with the correct geojson format and then parse them to ol3, like so:`var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON({}).readFeatures(jsonData);`

Comment: here you may get a proper syntax http://digitalservices.surreyi.gov.uk/developmentcontrol/0.1/applications/search?status=live&gsscode=E07000214&status=live it is very close to your data but you are missing `var geoJson = {
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":` and place your data here

Comment: Thank you @pavlos turns out I was using readFeatures badly, it works with your syntax